# If graph is not bipartite then every pair of vertices can be connected by a path of even length.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Can someone help me understand why if graph is not bipartite then we can connect every pair of vertices by a path of even length?

I can prove that if the graph is bipartite then we can assume that any two vertices are in a cycle together. For if it has a cut-path, delete it and continue by induction on the components. So any 2 verties must be in an even cycle, so any two vertices will be connected by a path of even legth.

However, we can't just say that if graph is not bipartite, then any 2 vertices can be in a path of odd length (while it is true if they are in an odd cycle). There should be some extra step.

Can someone please help? Thank you very much.

Comment: wikipedia has a picture of a bipartite graph with no cycles

Comment: Yes, but the point that we can assume it is 2-connected by deleting any bridge-paths if necessary, and proceeding by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the graph is connected.  Then every two vertices may be joined by a path.

Now, recall the result: a graph is [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Characterization) if and only if all its cycles have even length.  So, if the graph is not bipartite, there exists a cycle of odd length from a vertex $r$ to itself.

Now, consider two vertices $p$, $q$. Join $p$ with $r$ by a path, and $r$ with $q$ by a path. Concatenate these to get a path from $p$ to $q$. Now,  it this path has even length, we are done, if not, add in the middle the cycle of odd length from $r$ to itself. We thus get a path from $p$ to $q$ of even length.  (Note that we can also get a path of odd length from $p$ to $q$)

Observation: About the definition of a path: a sequence of vertices $(p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ such that $(p_{i-1},p_{i})$ is an edge for all $1\le i \le n$. The $p_i$ may not be distinct. The length of the path is $n$.

(This may have some other names, it is probably what it should mean in the statement of the problem).

Comment: Yes, I think your idea works, and I should have said "walk" in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is false. Let $G$ be the disjoint union of $K_2$ and $K_3$, like this:

$$\mid\quad\triangle$$

then $G$ is not bipartite, since it contains an odd cycle, but there is no path of even length between the two vertices of $K_2$.

A slight modification shows that requiring $G$ to be connected does not help, as the graph below is also a counterexample: there is no path of even length between $v$ and $w$.

```
                  v
                  |
                  w
                 / \
                *---*
```

Comment: I think the question assumes a connected graph.

Comment: @person: I shouldn’t be surprised, but in that case it needs to say so. (And it doesn’t help anyway, unless *path* is replaced by *trail* or *walk*.)

Comment: Is the converse true: if we can connect any 2 vertices by a path of even length, the graph has an odd cycle?

Comment: @user777: The contrapositive of what you said that you’re trying to prove is: if the distance $2$ graph is connected, then the original graph is not bipartite. But in this case I think that it’s at least as easy to prove the original implication: show that if $G$ is bipartite, there is no edge in the distance $2$ graph between the two parts.

Comment: True, that is much easier to see, because the vertices in bipartitions are connected only by a paths of odd length. But I saw a statement somewhere that if the distance-2 graph is disconnected then the original graph is bipartite. Am I right to think that in a distance-2 graph any 2 vertices are connected by a path iff there is a path of even length in the original graph? Then it should be true that if the graph is not bipartite, then the distance-2 graph is connected? But there is something wrong in my reasoning...

Comment: @user777: Suppose that there’s a path $v_1v_2\ldots v_n$ from $v_1$ to $v_n$ in the distance $2$ graph. That means that for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ there is a path of length $2$ between $v_k$ and $v_{k+1}$, but when you string those paths together, you don’t necessarily get a **path** from $v_1$ to $v_n$ in the original graph: you may only get a **walk**.